# Existence of a fixed point

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Am trying to prove the following statement!

Assume that $f:{\bf{R}}\rightarrow{\bf{R}}$ is a real function for which $f^{n}(c)=c$ for a *unique* real number $c$ and a positive integer $n$. (Here $f^{n}$ denotes the $n$-th iterate of $f$ i.e. $f$ composed with itself $n$ times). Prove that $c$ must be a fixed point of $f$.
The case $n=1$ is immediate, but the statement seems to be true if $f^{n}(c)=c$ for any positive integer $n$, provided $c$ is unique. I do not know if I require the hypothesis that $f$ be continuous. I could not construct a counter example with a discontinuous $f$. Sincere thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $c$ is the unique point such that $f^{n}(c) = c$, then we have $f^{n+1}(c) = f(c)$. Equivalently, $f^{n}(f(c)) = f(c)$. Thus $f(c)$ is a fixed point of $f^{n}$.

But $c$ is the \unique\ fixed point of $f^{n}$, so it must be $f(c) = c$, thus $c$ is a fixed point of $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $d := f(c)$. Then $f^n(d) = f^{n+1}(c) = f(f^n(c)) = f(c) = d$. As $c$ is unique, $d = c$, and thus $f(c) = c$.

Comment: This seems to imply that the fixed point $c$ of $f$ must be unique, for if $e$ were any fixed point of $f$ with $e\ne{c}$, then it would have to be the case that as $f(e)=e$, $f^{n}(e) = e$ contradicting the uniqueness of $c$. So if any iterate of $f$ has a unique fixed point, then $f$ must have a unique fixed point as well. Put another way, if $f$ has more than one fixed point, no iterate of $f$ can have a unique fixed point.

Comment: "Put another way, if $f$ has more than one fixed point, no iterate of $f$ can have a unique fixed point." This is trivial because a fixed point of $f$ also is a fixed point of each iterate of $f$.

Comment: Absolutely Friedrich. One should simply say that $c$ must the unique fixed point of $f$ and leave it at that. Thanks.